# Another Rest API relations

Tags: api, rest

ive been digging through quite a few questions on here about restful relations but havent quite found what im after.

consider this scenario

```
GET /api/users(?include=custom_fields) - returns an array of users, optionally including relations as nested properties

GET /api/users/1(?include=custom_fields) - returns a single user object

POST /api/users - creates a new user (if the request includes an array of "custom_fields" these are created and linked)

PUT /api/users/1 - replaces user entity with supplied payload

PATCH /api/users/1 - updates the user properties provided

DELETE /api/users/1 - deletes

GET /api/users/1/custom_fields - gets all users custom_fields

PUT /api/users/1/custom_fields - deletes all existing custom_fields and creates ones provided

PATCH /api/users/1/custom_fields - appends if not exists, or creates new custom fields for this user

DELETE /api/users/1/custom_fields - deletes all custom fields for user

DELETE /api/users/1/custom_fields/{id} - deletes custom field for use by id.
```

this all makes sense to me and is working as expected, however im now implementing a "user edit" screen in my admin area, this shows the user object AND the custom fields.

right now the only RESTFUL way i can see to save this form is to:

PATCH to /api/users/{id}

to save the user. when thats done,

PUT to /api/users/{id}/custom_fields

to update the custom fields.

not ideal but would work, however going forward i know for sure i will have other related resources like user roles, emails, etc.

this doesnt change the situation it just means alot more endpoints.

something about this smells to me. to simply save a user im having to make requests to at least two endpoints.

how would you suggest best to handle this without the two different requests?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to just include all those (custom fields, roles, etc.) into the `User` representation, you already seem to be doing that anyway on `GET` and `POST`. Just extend that to `PUT` and `PATCH` too.

If you already support some `media-type` for the `PATCH` method on Users, then you could conceivably extend that to define adding/removing custom fields, roles, whatever you need.